# How to Upgrade DevExPress from 9.3 to 12.1 ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

We have asp.net application using DevExpress 9.3 version and we have to upgrade to 12.1, what is the best way to upgrade ?

Comment: There is a tool for converting from old version to new version. Check this link http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2007/09/10/how-to-easily-convert-your-project-to-a-new-devexpress-release.aspx or this http://blog.magerquark.de/devexpress-version-switcher/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Project Converter](http://help.devexpress.com/#ProjectConverter/CustomDocument2529) tool for this purpose.

See the [Upgrade Notes](http://help.devexpress.com/#GeneralInformation/CustomDocument2221) topic for details.

Comment: in aspx  page in page directive it has reference to 9.3 version with cultural key info, do I need to update that info ?

Comment: Project converter will do that for you. I didn't have any problems using it. If you are not sure, search all files for your old version after converting project. However, you could encounter problems with breaking changes since you are upgrading from rather old version. Read Upgrade Notes topic Mikhail posted.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you just install the new version, then open the solution in the newer version, that's how Visual Studio, etc. works.  They should run in parallel and make backups, so trying won't be of any harm.

Comment: in aspx  page in page directive it has reference to 9.3 version with cultural key info, do I need to update that info ?

Answer (score 0):

- In Visual studio, click `DevExpress` -> `Project Converter` -> `Project Converter v15.2`

[image: access DevExpress project converter in VS]

- This will open up the project converter window

[image: DevExpress project converter window]

- There is no special need for fidgeting with the **Advanced Settings**
- Click <kbd>Upgrade</kbd>
- The `Project converter` tool might ask for confirmation about updating the read-only files
- Click <kbd>Yes to All</kbd>, to make sure that the tool doesn't disturb you for every next file

[image: confirmation for upgrading all files]

- To save the conversion log, click <kbd>Save Log</kbd> (optional)

[image: saving the conversion log]

- Click <kbd>Finish</kbd>

Visual Studio might get confused with some elements:

> 'XYZ' is an ambiguous reference between 'namespace ABC' and 'namespace DEF'

A few examples are:

- Replace `SelectedItemCollection` with `DevExpress.Web.SelectedItemCollection`

[image: Replace SelectedItemCollection with DevExpress.Web.SelectedItemCollection]

- Replace `Collection` with `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`

[image: Replace Collection with System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection]

- Clear the `Bin` and `Obj` folders as stated on [DevExpress' knowledge base](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18674)