# Could not load file or assembly Dev Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

Im develop asp.NET WEB APPLICATION,
Im removed V13.1.5 and after install new version 16.1.4 , now my project is not working, any one know how can i fix this issue 
Thanks

`Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Data.v13.1, Version=13.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Have you using Project Converter 16.1? You need to convert the project into latest version of DX before uninstalling previous one, or open the project with latest version of DX.

Comment: yeah im convert this , but not work

Comment: Have you convert after uninstalling v13.1? Seems that you need to add latest DX references manually into project, then change everything related with v13.1.5 to v16.1.4 (including `Register` directives in aspx page if exist).

Answer (score 0):

Open your .csproj file in a text editor and do a find and replace

1) 13.1.5 -> 16.1.4 and

2) 13.1 -> 16.1

Comment: How to find .csproj file, ?

Comment: @SamD It will be in the root folder of your web application project. It will actually be called <YOURWEBSITEPROJECTNAME>.csproj

Answer (score 0):

> The best way is to install the latest version to the Development
>   environment. After that, use the [Project Converter](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#ProjectConverter/CustomDocument2529) tool to
>   convert your existing application to the latest version. Once it is
>   done, test your application locally to correct errors, if any. Once
>   your application works flawlessly in the Development Environment,
>   deploy it to your Production environment.

See the [Upgrade Notes](http://help.devexpress.com/#GeneralInformation/CustomDocument2221) topic for details.

References:
[Devexpress update to latest version](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T228461)
[Updating ASP.NET WebSite Project from DevExpress v14.1.5 to the latest (currently v14.1.8)](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T181076)
[How to Upgrade DevExPress from 9.3 to 12.1 ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241683/how-to-upgrade-devexpress-from-9-3-to-12-1-asp-net)